# Php preg_replace To change image width

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have some images in my database

```
http://***.com/2013/12/reign-death-midseason-finale-featured.jpg?w=500
http://***.com/reign-death-midseason-finale-featured.png?w=120
http://***.com/2013/12/finale-featured.jpg?w=50
http://***.com/2013/finale-featured.jpg?w=50&h=50
http://***.com/2013/12/reign-death-midseason-finale-featured.jpg
```

I want to change the images with `w=` to same width and `?w=50&h=50` also. all with W should come as `w=600` and `w=600&h=600`. This is what I was trying `str_replace` but there is a problem with this that `w=` always change and in some cases there is height also and it also need to be changed, i have search net and found that it can be done with `preg_replace` don't know how.

**EDIT**

Answer needed is `if(hight is null)` result is `case 1 w=600` and `if h is not null case 2 w=600&h=600`
please help

Comment: please complete your question by explicitly stating the result you are looking for: `what you have` => case 1 `w=50`; case 2 `w=50&h50`. I don't really understand. You want to change all to the same number?

Comment: @hanzo2001 yes there are 2 cases 1st case result w=600 and 2nd i want same number for both like ?w=600&h=600

Comment: so you want to change every number to 600. Is this correct?

Comment: @hanzo2001 yes please

Comment: I hadn't seen your edit, ... no it's ok. I was wondering if there would be a `if width is null...` condition but you didn't ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry it took me a while, I was kinda busy

try the following

```
$pattern = '~(?<=\W(w|h)\=)(\d+?)(?=\D|$)~';
$replace = '600';
$subject = 'http://localhost/2013/finale-featured.jpg?w=50&h=50';
echo preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$subject);
```

try this with many variations of your URIs

PS: this kind of advanced string finding/replacing is the domain of regular expressions. If you find you need to do a lot of this, consider starting to learn about them, it's a whole language in itself. I used some **assertions** (lookahead `(?<=)` and lookbehind `(?=)`) for this particular solution

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using a regular expression you can parse the URL and query string into arrays, which would make evaluating the query string values much easier.

```
$url = 'http://***.com/2013/finale-featured.jpg?w=50&h=50';
$urlArray = parse_url($url);
parse_str($urlArray['query'], $queryStringArray);
if ( !isset($queryStringArray['h']) || $queryStringArray['h'] === null ) {

} else if ( ... ) {

} else if ( ... ) {

}
```